# Client ID no longer exists

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

When I try to run an Appscript I get error ..

> [17-02-08 01:00:35:160 PST] Open the following URL and re-run the script: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=317559754348->0p1ti3fmjae175i06hn07jrbia6701q6.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fscript.google.com%2Fmacros%2Fd>%2F1pgAT7ZCwiKrHx_7Iys770hJNRqTYwn9zioe9Qjvmhzc9rfIxO04P8Uum%2Fusercallback&state=ADEpC8xV9BMj3kqytygKLnjEYT7PX918NJg0i1oSCAsUTRwXcOgdzDStZA3lzGDK98CJ6OOhlDnlYEyyji5rx6P8haao8oDop->PMQBZsMMjk2Jl_GtsPnsifFDt1XjqSXtCS2Wx6X3fdLDHTlBzfwqvqrinfkHhW1dVw0oNv6-MaqDhimE912Po&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth>%2Fdevstorage.read_write&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&login_hint=imerrywe%40jaguarlandrover.com

Trouble is Client ID 317559754348-0p1ti3fmjae175i06hn07jrbia6701q6.apps.googleusercontent.com

no longer exists. Looks like it has accidentaly been deleted.
I have tried created new Oauth2 credentials but my appscript wants to use the old one.

How do I get my appscripts to use new credentials. ?

Regards,
Ian

```
// Global Project variables
var CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxx-
leuap166eur7gi5ufr6kiau2nqefknci.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

// OAuth2.0 Access token
var token;

function oAuth() {
    // Check we have access to the service
  Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
  Logger.log( Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail());

    var service = getService();
    Logger.log('Access '+service.hasAccess());
  var authInfo = ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL);
 Logger.log(authInfo.getAuthorizationStatus());
    if (!service.hasAccess()) {
        var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
        Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s', 
authorizationUrl);
        return;
    }
}

  function getService() {
// Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
// persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
// scope of the property store.
return OAuth2.createService('xxxxxxxxxx')

    // Set the endpoint URLs, which are the same for all Google services.
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')


    // Set the client ID and secret, from the Google Developers Console.
    .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
    .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)

    // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
    // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

    // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())

    // Set the scopes to request (space-separated for Google services).
    // this is admin access for the sqlservice and access to the cloud-        platform:
.setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform')

    // Below are Google-specific OAuth2 parameters.

    // Sets the login hint, which will prevent the account chooser screen
    // from being shown to users logged in with multiple accounts.
    .setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())

    // Requests offline access.
    .setParam('access_type', 'offline')

    // Forces the approval prompt every time. This is useful for testing,
    // but not desirable in a production application.
    .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');
}
```

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> The redirect URI in the request,  does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth >client. Visit >1 to update the authorized redirect URIs.

Comment: Do you have access to the apps script project? Do you know how to edit in the IDE?

Comment: I am writing the scripts at script.google.com. The scripts have previously worked ok.

Comment: I have added a simple script that re-creates the error. I tried setting variables to a different client_id but it seems to ignore this.

Comment: show the code where you setup `getService()`. Also is the client ID really broken over two lines in your code? It won't work as you have it in your example.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Slowly making progress, I didn't realise the getservice() function existed in a different script someone had sent me and was in my project. It was picking the code up from there. I have added the code. It is now trying to use the client_id specified but is still not authorised. When I copy and paste the authorisation url I now get an another error. I have added that to original post.

Comment: Check out the github repo for the OAuth2 library you are using it has the everything you need to get it set up correctly:
https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2

Comment: I couldn't enter the full url error message as stackoverflow is saying I cannot add more than two links.

Answer (score 0):

Just to address the

> 400. That’s an error. Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Go to your new `clientID`, below it you may need to add the "oauth2callback" redirect uri like:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/oauth2callback
```

[image]